# jQuery - change value of attribute

Tags: jquery

I don't know why this code not working good. I want change value of attribute "value" from "---" to "Day"

```
<select name="0-birthdate_day" id="id_0-birthdate_day">
<option value="0">---</option>
</select>

$("#id_0-birthdate_day").children().eq(1).attr("value").replace('0', 'Day')
```

Thanks

Comment: Well your question is not the same as your code...

Comment: The value of attribute `value` is `0`, not `---`. So which one do you want to change?

Comment: Truth, but for me some things in jQuery is like behind haze. Thanks for open my eyes for truth.

Comment: Cris: @Felix was asking you a question. Which do you want to change? The `0` or the `---`?

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#id_0-birthdate_day").children().eq(1).attr("value",function(i,val){
    return val.replace('0', 'Day');
});
```

You can give a function to `.attr()`. The return value will be the updated value.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$("#id_0-birthdate_day option[value='0']").text('Day');
```

Answer (score 2):

According to your question you want to change the text from `---` to `Day`.

This should do the trick:

```
jQuery("#id_0-birthdate_day option[value='0']").text('Day');
```

Basically it will find the `option` with value `0` and replace its text label with `Day`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#id_0-birthdate_day").find("option[value=0]").html('Day')
```

Answer (score 2):

To change the "value" from "---" to "Day" you would use the [.html function](http://api.jquery.com/html/), not the [attr() method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Comment: You might also consider using the text function ( http://api.jquery.com/text/ ) if the label contains special characters.